# PHP Class Property Using range()

Tags: php, oop

Here is a minimal test case I've isolated:

```
<?php

class What {
    public $foo = range(0,5);
}

?>
```

I have no idea why this produces an error:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in TestCase.php on line 4

Using `array()` works.

Using PHP 5.3.3 (bundled with OS X).

Comment: Your comment that "lots of other functions work" cannot be correct.

Comment: @konforce The moral of the story is, don't ask stack overflow questions super late at night. D:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only assign constant values in that context. You'll have to initialize your `$foo` in a constructor if you want to use the return value of a function.

```
<?php

class What {
    public $foo;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->foo = range(0,5);
    }
}

?>
```

BTW: As others have pointed out, `array()` is not a function. It's a language construct.

Answer (score 1):

Array isn't a function, it's a language construct. That's why it's allowed.

Answer (score 0):

> Class member variables are called "properties" ... may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Answer (score 0):

Check this link as a similar problem was sent and had been solved :-

http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/showthread.php?t=10366062

Also you can see the examples of using range() function in PHP.Net Manual although I think the problem may be in the variable $foo and public keyword as you there may be a type mismatch or a conflict beteen the version of the PHP function and your running PHP version.

I hope this answer helps you..

Comment: That's not the same issue. In that post, the user was using PHP version 4.4.6 which did not support the `public` and `private` access modifiers. In this question, the OP is using PHP version 5.5.3 which does support the `public` and `private` access modifiers.